# How to count word from list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I read data from json with this code .

```
json_file='report.json'

json_data=open(json_file)
data = json.load(json_data)

t0 = []
t1 = []
tn = []

#counts = Counter(data['behavior']['processes'][3]['calls'])
print (type(data['behavior']['processes'][3]['calls']))

for i in data['behavior']['processes'][3]['calls']:

    t0 = i['arguments']
    print(t0)

json_data.close()
```

it show data like this.

```
<class 'list'>
aa
bb
aa
cc
bb
cc
aa
```

I want to count frequentcy of word the result should be aa=3, bb=2, cc=2

If I uncomment at `Counter(data['behavior']['processes'][3]['calls'])` it will show error.

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

How to count word from list ?

Comment: Can you show us your sample data?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
Counter(map(lambda x:x['argument'], data['behavior']['processes'][3]['calls']))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
counterDict = {}   # <==
json_file='report.json'
json_data=open(json_file)
data = json.load(json_data)

t0 = []
t1 = []
tn = []

#counts = Counter(data['behavior']['processes'][3]['calls'])
print (type(data['behavior']['processes'][3]['calls']))

for i in data['behavior']['processes'][3]['calls']:

    t0 = i['arguments']
    counterDict[t0] = counterDict.get(t0,0)+1 # <===

json_data.close()

print(counterDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Counter requires a list as input.

```
from collections import Counter

#create a list from your data
mylist = [i['arguments'] for i in data['behavior']['processes'][3]['calls']]

#make a dict of counts
counter_dict = Counter(mylist)

#print out counts per item
for val in counter_dict:
    print '%i has %i occurrences' % (val, counter_dict[val])
```

(code untested)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it since i dont have the data you're using.
But i think this would work.

```
json_file='report.json'

json_data=open(json_file)
data = json.load(json_data)

t0 = []
t1 = []
tn = []

#counts = Counter(data['behavior']['processes'][3]['calls'])
print (type(data['behavior']['processes'][3]['calls']))

data_count = {}
for i in data['behavior']['processes'][3]['calls']:

    t0 = i['arguments']
    count = data_count.get(t0)
    if count is None:
        data_count[t0] = 1
    else:
        data_count[t0] = count + 1

    print(t0)

json_data.close()
print(data_count)
```